# Searching for remotely working industrial Scholarship For university department Students

Tags: funding, university, remote-work

I am biomedical Engineering student and CEO(chief executive officer) member of one new Medical device manufacturing Company (from third world countries), we have here many Students with no specific purpose and Experience in manufacturing some simple medical devices (such as [Dental Vacuum former](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QhUw3Lr77o)) with long time surfers and know if the university student of this field can want to do this works they have may problem to solving (like needs to multitasking designing, finding funds, market knowledge and ...).

So Two days ago, One of my University Professors said that there are some Scholarship  via internet which are between industrial or university organization based of their needs that could be done by remotely workers and no need to move from my base country.

Based of my working field and some other concerns (like money and ... !!!), I like to know more about this kind of Scholarship.

Specifically, about how could we create this kind of corporation between those Scholarship Investors and my University Biomedical Engineering Department with some goals like using  developing some of our industrial planes (Like Rehabilitation Exoskeleton designing or [Step Climber Wheelchair](https://github.com/GSH-Open-source-projects/Stair-climbing-wheelchair) ...) with sharing them with others organization with multi side benefit agreement? (Creating money for our university, Students and our company and ...)

I have read some answers to post like [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/what-are-useful-tips-and-tricks-for-collaborating-remotely):

> One of the hardest parts of remote collaboration is making sure
>   everyone is on the same page. Agreeing on work flow in advance is
>   critical. To me the most important thing is that everyone has a good
>   understanding of the roles and expectations of the individuals. A good
>   timeline, that is flexible, is also very useful. Agreeing upon
>   software, programming, and writing style issues at the outset is also
>   useful.

So thought this kind of works needs to have some more specific requirements and some symmetric searching fields between universities Professors and the second part, So I be happy to hear more about those.

I  know A little about the available platform for this kind of works (like **GitHub** and **git**) and eager to know your experiences in this field as well as you suggested measures to establish such partnerships in the absence of them.

I thought I can ask this question here based of this kind of question ([What are useful tips and tricks for collaborating remotely?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2071/what-are-useful-tips-and-tricks-for-collaborating-remotely)) and thought by myself maybe some university professors or student which involved on this kind of scholarship and hope to ... if this is off topic please advise me to Edit my Question to be more this forum oriented.

I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking about a scholarship or work?

Answer (score 0):

@moha_alpha-web.net,
Do you mean Remote base work for Student, like an Intern? Right.
If so, I will like to recommend some website to you whereby you can get a different type of remote job;
Like:
`Remotely.com`,
`outreachy.com`,
`Landingjob.com`,
`vanhack.com`,

I will like to know if you find any help with this.