# What are the advantages or disadvantages of using LaTeX for writing scientific publications

Tags: publications, writing, latex

What are objective advantages or disadvantages of using the markup language [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) instead of a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) word processor like MS Word or LibreOffice Writer?

Please use objective arguments to prevent a flame war...

Comment: In which field? Extensive use of mathematical formalism make a real difference.

Comment: In principle the question does not limit itself to only math heavy papers, although I think mathematical equations are one big advantage of LaTeX, so I suspect it will be part of a good answer

Comment: related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3054/675

Comment: Back in my Uni day's (early 90's) I used [TechWriter](http://www.mw-software.com/icon-tech/Products/TechWriter/TechWriter%20pro.html), on RISC OS, which offered the best of both worlds. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be anything as functional today (unless you obtain an old copy, and run it under an emulator or Raspberry Pi), but there are LaTex export [Wizards](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/) available for all the popular office suites, if you can live with the quotation editors (the one in word used to be very buggy, but haven't used it in years).

Comment: In 1994 I was asking myself the same question. FrameMaker was my final choice as it was WYSIWYG, decent cross references, ran under MacOS and Solaris, supported PS/PDF output, integrated color graphics and equation editor, etc. It's still way better than Word, IMO, but costs too much. Adobe bought the company and aimed the product at a niche market (SGML).

Comment: I find it ridiculously difficult to manage documents with a large number of figures in Word. Word seems to do its own thing when minor changes are made. With Latex, I get exactly what I want. Stopped using MSWord years ago. My advice would be to bite the bullet and learn LaTex. Steep learning curve, but the results are well worth the effort...and then some.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

LaTeX is better at:

- **Dealing with mathematical notation**. Layout and entry are generally easier using LaTeX than some other sort of equation editor.
- **Consistent handling of intra-document references and bibliography**. As of a couple of years ago the major WYSIWYG editors still had problems with re-numbering cross-references and bibliography items. This is never a problem with BibTeX or LaTeX.
- **Separation of content and style**. In principle this means that you can write your document without caring how it is formatted, and at the end of the day wrap it in the style-file provided by the journal publisher before submission to conform to the house style. In practice some of the journal publishers demand special formatting commands that partially moots this process. Furthermore recent versions of Word and LibreOffice Writer, when properly used, should be able to keep track of various levels of section heading separate from the body text, and apply uniform styling to each level. The gap is somewhat closing.
- **Tables and illustrations**. With PSTricks or TikZ, one can produce high quality illustrations *within* the document (though the learning curve is a bit steep there). And I've found LaTeX to be better at preparing complex tables.

WYSIWYG (especially Word and Writer) is better at:

- **Collaborative editing**. Without using an online site for collaborative LaTeX editing (such as ShareLaTeX), working collaboratively on a LaTeX file ideally requires some sort of separate revision control software. Word and Writer have very good comments/annotations and edit-tracking features. When a large number of authors are commenting on the writing of one file, this can be very useful.
- **Spell check**. Admittedly most text editors one uses to edit TeX files also do spell check. But this is generally conveniently built into WYSIWYG editors.
- **Compatibility**. Unless you work in mathematics, computer science, or physics (and sometimes even if you work in those fields), it is more likely that your collaborators will know what to do with a Word or Writer file than a LaTeX file.
- **Minimum barrier to entry**. If you just care about getting the ideas down on paper, you can use a WYSIWYG editor just like a typewriter. Sure, it may be tedious to fix the formatting later on, compared to LaTeX where one need to first figure out how to setup a bare-minimum file before using, it may be an attractive point.

A wash:

- Most journals provide templates for both Word and LaTeX, so there's no real winner there.

---

Suggestion: if you want to convince someone to start using LaTeX, start them out first in one of the WYSIWYG environments designed for LaTeX first (for example [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/)). This will help somewhat to ameliorate the scary entry barrier.

Comment: +1 The separation of content and formatting is hard to get right in Word, and trivial in LaTeX.

Comment: In addition, if you have them using LyX, don't do collaborative editing with someone else not using LyX. LyX is idiosyncratic and LyX documents don't easily compile with other LaTeX flavors

Comment: good answer! Totally agree. and +1 here: it's fun to use LaTeX.

Comment: I agree, but I have a comment. LaTeX does not really separate content and formatting. If LaTeX is used properly, you'll practically get content and formatting mostly separated, but LaTeX does not enforce this. It's common to see "{\bf foo}" and numerous minor tweaks to get formatting look right, such as "\vskip{1ex}", in LaTeX documents. XHTML/CSS gets separation right at a conceptual level.

Comment: @Suresh: What are you talking about? LyX is not a LaTeX flavor, but a front-end. Just export its documents as LaTeX, and you can collaborate with others.

Comment: @KarsusRen I realize that Lyx is a front-end. I've had problem with the latex that gets exported from lyx.

Comment: @Jan: I agree. Hence "LaTeX is better at [it]" and not "LaTeX forces you to [it]". And for argument's sake neither does XHTML/CSS do it. There's nothing preventing you from defining a `<div class=boldface> </div>` that does exactly the same function as `{\bf foo}`. (Ever try reading some of the code produced by inferior WYSIWYG front ends for editing web pages?)

Comment: Just to add - LaTeX has been getting easier to learn and use with the rise of a number of online LaTeX editors that do the compiling for you and offer a real time preview of the output, such as [writeLaTeX.com](https://www.writelatex.com). We're hoping this will lower some of the barriers to entry (I'm one of the developers of writeLaTeX, and so any feedback is much appreciated, thanks)

Comment: I strongly disagree with your claim that Word is better at collaborative editing. Track changes is okay but it simply doesn't compare with the power and robustness of version control software. Consider what would happen if you both make changes to the same revision of a word document.

Comment: @Jack: VCS is _not_ part of LaTeX. Whereas Word has change tracking built-in. In fact, I said as much in my answer above.

Comment: @WillieWong: No, it's not part of LaTeX but one of the principle benefits of LaTeX is that it plays nicely with VCS. To ignore it is missing a major part of what makes LaTeX better. Like many such tools, LaTeX is sensibly viewed as part of a _suite_ than a standalone option otherwise you may as well complain that LaTeX has no editor when in fact everyone who uses LaTeX uses a well featured text editor to work with it. The point remains that proper VCS blows Word's "Track Changes" out of the water.

Comment: @Jack: I do not disagree with you that a good VCS is, well, good. But you cannot 'sell' LaTeX to the masses by saying that "oh yeah, for this other thing? LaTeX totally wins if you install this other power-user software". Like it or not, [the Unix philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) is not very ingrained for most "users" of computers. LaTeX has enough of a learning curve as it is, you don't want to scare users away _in the beginning_ by saying "oh, and you also need `git`, and `asymptote`, and while you are at it learn `lua`..."

Comment: @WillieWong: On this, I think, we shall have to agree to disagree.

Comment: you should try ShareLaTeX https://www.sharelatex.com?referal=ed73b7dd
 you can collaboratively edit on that, and without any prior configurations

Comment: "Most journals provide templates for both Word and LaTeX, so there's no real winner there." - Citation needed. Almost no journals in my field provide LaTeX templates.

Comment: @Fomite: The three big-name publishers, Reed-Elsevier, Springer, and Wiley account for 40% of the academic publications. [Elsevier has a standard article class](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/latex-instructions), as does [Springer](http://www.springer.com/authors/journal+authors?SGWID=0-154202-12-417499-0) (see also [the CTAN listing](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/springer)). Wiley has [one for books](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-301843.html), but it seems they are slightly less keen on LaTeX [for their journals](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129529/119).

Comment: @Fomite: and for some of the other publishers. [Nature does not have their own class, but gives simple and clear guidlines](http://www.nature.com/srep/authors/submit.html), [PLoS](http://www.plosone.org/static/latexGuidelines) and [PNAS](http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/LaTex.xhtml) both provide templates, as does [Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/site/feature/contribinfo/prep/prep_init.xhtml). Granted, the popularity of LaTeX is field-dependent, and it is quite possible that in your particular subfield it is not as popular to prepare manuscripts in LaTeX.

Comment: ... but on the flip side, in my field manuscripts _not_ prepared in LaTeX are often looked upon with suspicion. So the cut goes both ways.

Comment: Re: separation of content and formatting. Take a look at Knuth's TeX book, there are hand-tweaked formatting modifications all over the place. Many of them are necessary because TeX is so dumb regarding character shapes -- it knows nothing about a character except its enclosing box, so it can't possibly do a decent job.

Comment: @bubba: if that's the sort of details you care about, you might find [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) useful.

Comment: @WillieWong: I do not disagree with your statements about how Word integrates certain parts of version control tools that would come in separate packages for LaTeX (and how that is easier for some users). I think, though, it should also be noted, that the *document exchange* part of VCS is *not* integrated in Word, but that a separate system, such as a SharePoint Server, is required, to actually work collaboratively on a document. In that case, conflicts are handled in some way (because changes are visible to all users in real-time), but it is *not* contained out of the box; with a plain ...

Comment: ... Word installation, for example, you have the comments and track changes features - as well as options that can be manually invoked to reintegrate several versions of a document -, but you still have to exchange the latest documents by e-mail or by having everyone work on a mutual exchange directory on a network drive - and heaven forbid if two people work on that file on such a network drive simultaneously and one of them simply overwrites the file that the other one has just saved their day's work to.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: good points, in all. I should mention that also a VCS is not a magic bullet. For example, for large documents if one does not take advantage of `\include` and `\input` statements and works with a monolithic `.tex` file, conflict resolution will take more time than those saved by not using e-mail to pass the file back and forth.

Comment: @bubba The TeXbook is about TeX itself and the "plain TeX" format, not LaTeX.  One of the big contributions of LaTeX was its strong encouragement of separating content from formatting.

Comment: @AndreasBlass -- the same comment holds for the LaTeX Companion.

Comment: @bubba, Knuth writes in TeX, the low-level language on which LaTeX is built. Yes, you can can screw around with such micromanagement in LaTeX too, but that mostly negates it's usefulness.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, with Word you are *forced* to use the dumb GUI, the (crappy) VCS included, and so on. With LaTeX you choose the tools you most like (and can use them also to edit and save code, random text snippets, experimental data, ...).

Comment: @vonbrand: Unfortunately, "choos[ing] the tools you most like" is not a selling point towards users who want an everything-out-of-the-box solution. Accordingly, in my experience, these users tend to perceive it as a negative to have n + 1 tools (n editing tools + 1 VCS), compared to n tools (n editing tools, each with its integrated VCS features).

Answer (score 44):

## Word

*Advantages:*

- Minimal learning curve
- [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)
- Ridiculously high install base; almost guaranteed that anyone can read/edit your file without modifying anything
- Easy-to-use reviewing tools (view changes, add comments, etc)

*Disadvantages:*

- Layout can be a real bear to get correct
- Math is difficult, slow, and often ugly
- Included bibliography editor is virtually unusable for most scientific writing; you'll need to buy a third-party solution to manage your bibliography

## LaTeX

*Advantages*:

- It's just text; anyone can edit your file
- You don't have to worry about layout, it's all automatic. Just put the words down there and you're golden
- Produces aesthetically beautiful documents
- Easy to use math, symbols, etc
- Once learned, much faster and more intuitive (e.g., `\label` and `\ref` for referencing, as opposed to Word's fairly kludgy "Cross-referencing" window which requires way too many clicks to insert a single reference)

*Disadvantages:*

- Fairly steep learning curve
- Collaborators unfamiliar with LaTeX will have difficulty reviewing your manuscripts
- Many features require libraries, which you have to find/be made aware of (view changes, etc)
- Layout changes are difficult (i.e., will require time for you to hunt down solution and implement it)

Comment: +1 cross-referencing in LaTeX is a breath of fresh air in comparison to Word.

Comment: "Layout changes are difficult" is an _advantage_ of LaTeX, not a disadvantage.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on why this is an advantage?

Comment: Some layout changes are extremely easy in LaTeX, and I find it an advantage (switching between double spaced, figures and tables at end review format to nicely typeset two-column)

Comment: Also, hearing my colleages comment under their breath at Office2010, I beg to differ on the minimal learning curve...

Comment: Maybe what is meant here by `minimal learning curve` is that just about everyone can open word and start typing. Using e.g. Word effectively has a much steeper learning curve.

Comment: @JeffE - Spending time figuring out how to change the default margins, or how to allow plots to take up more than 80% of the page, or other details like that can be a royal pain in the keister.

Comment: @eykanal But...you're using the class the journal provided (i.e. revtex in my business) so you don't *want* to change the margins or column count. And if you're writing a book or other independent publication you'll be using memoir or a similar class where those things are clearly and copiously documented, right?

Comment: @eykanal: Having done my fair share of LaTeX hacking, I agree with you completely.  Which is why even I don't get distracted by it very often.  Also: \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} \def\topfraction{0.9}

Comment: Figure placement is a bear in LaTeX. Not so much in WYSIWIG editors.

Comment: Additional disadvantage of LaTeX: some of its core has not evolved in years. For example, [web page citation formats are still not supported properly in BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69033/17868)

Comment: @Suresh Figure placement is *easy* in LaTeX: the compiler does it for you. *Forcing* the figure placement is harder and can be a real bear, but I find that I generally don't need to mess with it.

Comment: I agree that "layout changes are diffucult" is an advantage. In order to set up some layout, you should have some experience. For example: Many people want to have the same margin on left and right pages and then print their document on double sided. Or they want the first pages in a chapter to look like the rest. 

Normally, if some students are telling me that they want to change all those things, I give them some professional text book and let them find out what is done there.

Comment: @dmckee figure placement may be automatic, but it's often crappy, especially with two-column format.

Comment: "Collaborators unfamiliar with LaTeX will have difficulty reviewing your manuscripts" - disagree, everybody can open and annotate a PDF! I agree that collaborators may dislike this compared to Word, though, and complain that it makes things difficult, and this may cause friction. And it isn't quite as nice as Track Changes.

Comment: The zeal of (La)TeX afficionados never ceases to amaze me. The answers given here are quite balanced and rational, IMO, which is pretty unusual in this on-going debate.

Comment: Yes, most everybody can *read* a Word document. On the other hand, the people I know who even are aware that Word can be used to format larger documents, has ways of tweaking formats, manages crossreferences, and all what is *required* for "real work" can be counted with the fingers of one hand.

Answer (score 44):

I am currently studying for a PhD (engineering, almost done) and I supervised some student projects (diploma thesis and so on). Therefore I experienced both the typical Word and LaTeX workflow.

Most of the points are already mentioned in the very good other answers. I just want to add some general comments. Since I am not a geek I think that I can give roughly an average opinion.

### The Typical Word User

- Almost every student was complaining about mysterious behaviour like disappearing pictures or lost formatting.
- In addition, it happened quite often that large documents get somehow corrupted and it wasn't possible to edit/open it again. Then the students had to fall back on one of their backups.
- The larger the document the harder it is to keep the typography consistent. Because it is so easy to edit the text manually (this one bold, that one italic and so on) the students usually pay little attention to the systematic use of style sheets (don't know if that's the correct English term).
- Dealing with complex mathematical expressions is painful.
- Many of the settings are done using some menu entry and so it is very hard to document the settings or to make comments on how or why someone did something.
- Only one out of 100 students knows that you can work with vector graphics (in this case EPS) in Word. So most of the figures are ugly.
- In the last days of the thesis it is an advantage in Word that you can -- in the case of an emergency -- just draw anything everywhere in order to meet specific goals.
- It is hard to reuse content in Word -- I mean reuse it that way, that a change at one instance affects all instances.
- ...

It is not important whether all this happened because of a unprofessional use of Word -- the point is, that it happens.

### The Typical LaTeX User

- You need a friend!: It is almost suicide to start using LaTeX on your own when you start writing your last and most important thesis at university. This can only work if you have a friend or colleague (like me) who can give you a template and a crash course.
- Almost all students who decided to use LaTeX reported that they had fun using it! I think the main reason is that the documents look very professional without doing much.
- In addition, students find it "cool" that the output is directly a PDF with hyperlinks and so on. Most of the normal WORD users don't create cool PDFs.
- Students like the fact that they can easily input PDF files like datasheets to the appendix. This way they even appear in the table of content (TOC). I have never seen a Word document with a detailed TOC for the appendix. This is especially important in the field of engineering.
- Using/creating bibliographies is not fun. But after they figure it out it works fine.
- The concept of using a distribution like MiKTeX or TeXLive is new to most of the students and confusing at the beginning. In addition they sometimes can't distinguish between LaTeX itself and the LaTeX text editor (e. g. Texmaker). Therefore I made a video tutorial for that ;): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RL15I-6NQFQ

Comment: Very good answer. It is true that the WYSIWYG editors are getting better in separeting content and layout as Willie Wong pointed out. But I don't know many people using it.

Up to my experience, this is the normal workflow. But maybe the people had fun with LaTeX since only the brave ones tried. I know some people giving it up after a very short try.

Comment: Despite this post being "already" 1.5 years ago, it still holds so true. It kind of made me smile...

Comment: We built up a central BibTeX database (including all texts referenced, another file for papers written by us, another for theses, and so). Everybody used it and added to it, occasionally one of us went over new entries (version control!) and fixed/completed them.

Answer (score 28):

As primary author I usually use LaTeX, most colleagues use word, so I (have to) use that when contributing to papers.

Advantage of LateX:

- Mathematical equations were mentioned already.
- More important for me is that pure-text formats work better with literate programming tools like [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/)/[knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) (I do data analysis in R)
  These tools also produce graphics and automatically put them into the paper
- pure text formats work well with version control

  - I use `latexdiff` to produce versions with highlighted changes automatically
  - `git diff --color-words` is good for seeing changes and is not confused by changes in the line.
- Lightweight in terms of computational resources for typing
- Publishers have document classes that will format the text. Allows to produce nicely readable author's versions.
  By loading few packages (or even only setting some option) you can switch back and forth to the ridiculously unreadable format the publisher demands.
- Bibliography styles: changing the style allows to switch back and forth between e.g. references with title and linked doi and the journal's requested format without.

Disadvantages:

- many coworkers don't use/know it
- believe it or not, but even pdf files can be problematic wrt. printing/display.

Side Note:

- Lyx provides [WSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM) on top of Latex.

Advantages of Word

- Almost everyone has it

Disadvantages

- Resource demanding
- No/difficult literate programming (Openoffice works, though not as nicely as LaTeX)
- Problems between versions
- (Problems with merging versions which is supposed to work)

---

#### Literate programming and paper.

[Here's an example.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1323) I didn't go the full length of literate programming for the whole article: the simulation in section 3 took some week on our server blade, so that was done separately and I just pulled in the result graphics. But I wrote section 4 in Sweave, so the calculated numers end up automatically in the text. A slightly modified .Rnw file of the calculations in section 4 (`knitr` version) is `supplementary-code.Rnw` in the sources.

- *(I just saw that I forgot to upload the .Rnw for the whole paper to arXiv, and it wouldn't let me do it when I just tried - I'll correct this, probably when I have the final volume/pages for the journal)*
- Why `Sweave` and `knitr`: I prepared the document in `Sweave` (and without any caching as two of the coauthors use R as well. So they automatically have `Sweave`. I wanted to keep the dependecies low. However it turned out that they did not wish to run it. Next paper will use only `knitr`, and cache longer calcluations.
- It is a trade-off: typing in the numbers is faster than the lengthy `Sweave`/`knitr` code. But then you need to re-read the paper so carefully to make sure you have no typo somewhere in there, which takes a lot of time, too.

Comment: Could you expand more on the literate programming?

Comment: I second Paul's request. I would love to see an example of literate programming being useful in writing a scientific paper.

Comment: @WillieWong combining R and LaTeX seems to be the pinnacle of reproducible research. Creating the paper, including the statistical analyses, requires you to just rerun the scripts, i.e. a one step procedure. In practice I find it hard to implement, especially because some of my analyses take quite long. Take a look at `knitr` for a good integration of R and LaTeX.

Comment: A list of examples of reproducible analysis: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/complete-substantive-examples-of-reproducible-research-using-r

Comment: @JeromyAnglim: thanks for the link. I wasn't aware of that list.

Comment: Re: pdf produced by LaTeX - I have found also that some documents aren't "searchable" or "copyable", but they tend to be older docs (ps2pdf?). In some very strange cases, you *can* copy and search, but the text doesn't correspond to what appears on the screen (strange character encodings).

Comment: Here's a related post on using git with latex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6190412

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: I suggest saving the results of your analyses to a database. Then you won't have to run the analyses every time you compile your LaTeX document.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: I suspect the PDF viewer has its part in that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Here's an example of a broken PDF. Try it with whatever viewer you can find: http://carbon.utsi.edu/downloads/JRobertson_MSER.pdf Read more at http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/1ewdwz/

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: I cannot reproduce the issues described in the forum posting - when using full-text search on the PDF while displayed in the PDF viewer plugin of Firefox 31 on Windows (in general, a viewer that I dislike, due to some other issues such as lazy loading), the search for *the* does not fail as described in the forum, but correctly highlights occurrences of the word *the* (at least the first few of them, as far as I tried). Likewise, searching for *ac* like that correctly highlights that substring, e.g. in *Abstract*, then in *characterisation*, then in *fraction* etc.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Interesting. I will check out that PDF Viewer.

Answer (score 15):

The following is based on [*LaTeX and Friends*](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html).

**Cons**

- *Difficult to learn and use.*  True, but it will save you time in the long run, even if you're writing a minor thesis.
- Not WYSIWYG. True, but there are many IDEs. For example, [TeXWorks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/), [TeXMaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/), [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/), ....
- *Little support for physical markup.*  True, but this is a good thing.  It ensures your document style is consistent.  Also it saves time because fiddling with style *will* cost you time.
- *Using non-standard fonts is difficult.*  This used to be true but nowadays installing new fonts is relatively easy.
- *No spell checking.*  True, but some IDEs support it. Also you can spell-check at the command line level.
- *Too many packages.*  Yes, it may be difficult to find the right package.  However, asking a question in [*TeX Stack Exchange*](http://tex.stackexchange.com) or [`comp.text.tex`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.text.tex)  will quickly give you an answer.  Also you usually only need a few core packages, which you can package as a user-defined library.
- *LaTeX is for techies only.* False, LaTeX is used in mathematics, computer science, physics, life sciences, humanities, ....
- *Encourages structured writing.*  Some people don't like this. Others do.

**Pros**

- *Separation of style and content.* LaTeX is a procedural markup language sitting on top of a typesetting engine. You make the purpose of your writing explicit by annotating (marking up) your writing. LaTeX uses the markup to typeset your writing in the right style.
- *Trust.* In a recent *TUGboat* (Volume 33, Number 3, 2012) Boris Veytsman writes an interesting paper that shows that using *Computer Modern* (the default LaTeX font) increases the level of trust people have in written statements: it came second, closely following *Baskerville,* which came first. At the lower end of the scale of trustworthyness is *Comic Sans*. (Results based on results from Morris.)
- *Generation of plots and tables.* LaTeX has packages that automate the generation of plots and tables. You provide the data and the packages do the typesetting. If done properly, this ensures that all plots and tables are typeset in the same consistent style.
- *Technical diagrams.* LaTeX has packages that can generate technical diagrams such as trees, state transition machines, petri nets, and so on. Using these packages guarantees a consistent presentation.
- *High-quality typesetting and good automatic hyphenation.* This inludes kerning, real small caps, common and non-common ligatures, glyph variants, .... LateX's hyphenation is second to none.
- *Many conferences and publishers accept LaTeX.* This is useful because it guarantees your paper will comply with the conference's formatting guidelines.
- *Turing-complete programming language!* This lets you compute things that you can then typeset (similar to a spreadsheet with input and output columns).
- *Write notes/book/presentation in same source file.*  This is related to the previous item.  LaTeX can make decisions and this lets you write several output documents in one input document. For example you may have a presentation version and a notes version. You can share text for both versions and use some text for just one version.
- *LaTeX is highly configurable.* For example, you can define your own book/paper style and package the settings as a library so you can use them over and over again.
- *You can translate LaTeX to `html`, `ps`, `pdf`, `DocBook`, ...*
- Automatic numbering of sectional units, figures, ... This guarantees consistency of the output document. In addition LaTeX provides a consistent and easy cross-referencing mechanism.
- *Excellent Bibliography support.* LaTeX automates the typesetting of the citations and the generation of the bibliography/references.  It lets you control the style of both citations and references. The result is a perfect bibliography and consistent citations.
- *Very stable, free, and available on many platforms*. Who doesn't want that?
- *Large and active, friendly, and helpful user-base.* Ask a question in  [*TeX Stack Exchange*](http://tex.stackexchange.com) or [`comp.text.tex`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.text.tex) and you usually get a detailed answer in minutes.
- *LaTeX has comments.* So you can remember why/how something worked.
- *Can produce [coffee stains](http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349) on your papers.*  So you have *consistent* coffee stains on your papers!
- *Most importantly: LaTeX is fun!*

Comment: Coffee stains are definitely a must.

Comment: I would echo the pro about LaTeX having comments as a very useful tool. As a novice writer I find it helpful to organize my writing (even within paragraphs) by adding comments to say what the goal of that chunk is (e.g. Summarize main findings) or to include some raw results in comments next to the text summarizing them. 

Of course you can get comments with WYSIWYG editors but I find the purpose is different (mainly collaboration and revisions) rather than notes to self.

Comment: @av1 It's a very useful feature indeed. If you like annotating your writing with comments, you may want to check out [folds](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41814/10274), which are supported by some editors.

Answer (score 14):

I am a freelance writer, writing mostly articles and fiction, and I prefer LaTeX over Word for a few reasons:

- I work much faster in Vim, which is perfect for editing LaTeX markup
- I write in a modular fashion, so LaTeX's \input{} (command/markup/whatever) is indespensible.
- I can convert LaTeX markup to any format I need, most of the time directly: pdfs, docs, html, epub, etc.
- Word's graphical nature is too much overhead when I can simply open vim, type what I need, add a preamble, some markup and a style file, run the document through aspell and be done.

Comment: This site is mostly for Graduate Students and Academia, I do not  think this is a proper forum for these kind of answers, fiction writing is too different from scientific writing

Comment: @Leonpalafox yet in this case I think the answer is relevant.

Comment: @Leonpalafox Graduate students in English, or MFA students, will surely be surprised to know that they don't belong in Academia.

Answer (score 9):

### LaTeX

1. Open source free software. Even the [FSF thinks so](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#GPLIncompatibleLicenses).
2. Stable: The current version of LaTeX is from 1994, the underlying program (TeX) is from 1982. You can easily process a document made with LaTeX 2.09 in 1987 with a modern TeX distribution on modern hardware
3. Runs on any modern operating system on any hardware

### Word

1. Closed source expensive proprietary software (MS Word)
2. Unstable: The document format of Word is constantly changing. You will be hard pressed to open a document from say Word 2003 with a recent version; getting all your formatting from a Word 5.5 document (1991) [will probably be impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Word#Attempts_at_cross-version_compatibility). [ODF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODF) created by Open/Libre Office helps here.
3. Runs only on Windows and OSX (Word) or Linux (Open/Libre Office). Porting Open/Libre Office to a different operating system is a major undertaking.

Comment: I'm afraid these (well-know) facts don't address the academic side of the question. Noöne here wants to launch a (∞+1)th flamewar on this topic…

Comment: Open/Libre Office runs on Windows, Mac, Linux, FreeBSD, OpenBSD. What else do you need it for, a Commodore 64?

Comment: @F'x: Stability isn't an issue in academia?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I remember the effort of porting it to OpenBSD: It was massive and a major undertaking. Oh and for the other os - what about an iOS port?

Comment: @MartinSchröder good point - I don't own a tablet, so I didn't consider tablet OS's at all.

Comment: @MartinSchröder what I meant is no point in your answer is specific to academia…

Comment: @F'x: Stability is specific to academia, since works there can take years (e.g. thesis) and books can be updated for decades (e.g. tacop).

Comment: @MartinSchröder there are plenty non-academic writers who take years to write a book, and plenty technical books that are non-academic and yet updated for decades (dictionaries and standards, to give only two examples)…

Answer (score 9):

An additional advantage of LaTex that I haven't seen listed among the many answers here is that:

LaTex source files can be (fairly) easily generated by a script or other program.  In some research areas, you might be generating lots of data that needs to be put into tables or figures in your text.  In my case, I had a computer simulation that generated the data.  I programmed the simulation output to add a little bit of LaTex instructions here and there in the data and the output file then became part of my LaTex source document.  No cut-n-paste.  No danger of re-typing a value incorrectly.  If I found a bug in my simulation (hypothetically speaking, of course), then I can easily regenerate the data and associated markup very easily.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently switched to LaTex whilst at university and the response has been great. I have written an number of reports regarding projects and tutors were happy to see somebody using the proper software.

I have found that with larger projects that it can be split up into sections and I'm currently writing a document that is split up into a number of chapters which is very easy to manage the document.

With regard to technical documentation such as tables, diagrams and equations it does require some learning but it is very useful indeed.

Another thing to note is that the document structure is kept consistent throughout, sections and chapters are correctly numbered as well as the references, footnotes and figures all being correctly numbered.

Also, use BibDesk as it helps out tremendously when using a number of citations.

Comment: +1, although what is proper of not is a point of debate.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post my take on this, as a Word user who has oft pondered switching to LaTeX but has decided not to (but has collaborators who do):

**Word**:

*Advantages*

1. Universality. While Microsoft Office isn't 100% ubiquitous, I'm willing to say that very nearly everyone has the ability to modify Word or Word-like documents in some form. A Word file can by and large be sent under the assumption that the recipient will know what to do with it. I'd be similarly willing to bet that the installed base of any sort of TeX distribution is far lower.
2. Non-technical. There isn't much of a learning curve to Word, and there is a pretty steep one for LaTeX. I collaborate with a lot of non-technical colleagues, who will be writing or commenting on policy or clinical questions. Getting them to use Doodle to schedule a call is hard enough, I cannot imagine what LaTeX would be like. On the other hand, virtually everyone who can use LaTeX can also use word.
3. "Track Changes" is a decent reviewing tool, and may be considerably more intuitive than looking at diffs in a version tracker or something like that.
4. In some fields, Word will be the assumed-upon format for journal submissions. This is, of course, not universally true, but it's worth noting in the sometimes computation-heavy world of Stack Exchange that academia as a whole doesn't necessarily use LaTeX.

*Disadvantages*

1. Word. Is. Not. Layout. Software. Attempting to use it as such is an exercise in frustration.
2. Word definitely emphasizes text over mathematical notation. While it has been getting significantly better, and isn't actually an impediment in my work, for very equation-heavy documents, it will become tiresome.
3. Citation management requires a third party package of some sort - the one that is built-in is criminally poor.

**LaTeX**

*Advantages*

1. LaTeX is just better for math typesetting. Whether this is important or not is a question, but that LaTeX is better at it is something about which reasonable people can't so much disagree.
2. As text-based documents, LaTeX files play really nicely with version control software.
3. The overall layout tools available for LaTeX are vastly superior to Words, and much more amenable to templates, standard code, etc. You could write a script to automatically put in all the preambulatory info (affiliation, headings, etc.) for a LaTeX document. Doing that in Word would be...hard.

*Disadvantages*

As a disclaimer, some of these are fairly subjective.

1. Anything listed as one of Word's advantages. The biggest for me is the high probability that a collaborator will go "What am I supposed to do with this?" and we'll end up in Word anyway.
2. In my experience, compilation errors and the like definitely crop up when trying to pass LaTeX files between multiple authors.
3. Laying out an adequate LaTeX document is easy. Laying out a *nice* LaTeX file is hard. I often encounter a sense that "Once it's in LaTeX it's done", and while that's more true than it is for a Word document, it's a far cry from something that's professionally typeset.

Comment: I've seen my share of Word documents that misbehaved horribly. One particular case was a template to apply for internal monies here. The secretary who created it went to the trouble to add tables that calculated some of the data automatically (some percentages, summary of costs, and so). Infuriatingly, it worked ***only*** on her copy of Word; on other, exactly the same computer model, operating system, and so on, the tables just calculated gibberish. Take some old document, it will get repaginated (fun when you carefully tweaked the text so no page starts with an equation).

Comment: @vonbrand In my experience, it happens more with LaTeX documents than Word, but of course it can still happen.

Comment: LaTeX works the same everywhere, Errors crop up when packages aren't installed, or a part of the text is transplanted elsewhere. Laying out nice LaTeX is trivial (stick to the standard classes), laying out a complex, non-standard LaTeX document requires a professional (small wonder, typesetting is *not* trivial), but there are classes (`memoir`) and bundles (`KOMA`) that allow a non-specialist to tweak a lot.

Comment: @vonbrand I've had teams working together for years still end up sending early in the morning emails right before a deadline with errors. It may work that way in theory, but again, *in my experience*, it crops up a fair amount.