# Should I learn to use LaTeX to write up a History Masters Thesis?

Tags: thesis, masters, writing, latex, formatting

So I reviewed the "[What are the advantages or disadvantages of using LaTeX for writing scientific publications?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5414/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-latex-for-writing-scientific-p)" question on this forum and am sitting on the fence at the moment whether or not to use LaTeX to write up my masters Thesis.

I get the feeling that it is best suited for Scientific work but my MLitt is in History. I have searched my university website about LaTeX and most results come back from the maths department.

I am a part-time research student so my thesis with be approx. 50,000 words. At the moment I am using Libreoffice (I'm a Linux user -Ubuntu distro) to write up each chapter as a separate document which I was going to bring into a master theses document. I am using Mendeley to manage all my footnotes and bibliography.

I'm going to be meeting my supervisor over the next couple of weeks and would like to discuss the matter with him as to if I should/can use LaTeX. I'm sure how familiarity or usage of LaTeX within the History department will impact on my decision but would also like to prepare my thesis in the best possible way.

> Edit 10/04/14: After a meeting with my Supervisor it appear that the History department has no preference on software for writing the thesis. Only requirement is that final thesis before defence is printed in ring-bound cover and the (hopefully!) accepted thesis is a hardback bound copy. My last written piece to my supervisor was done in LaTeX, using Texmaker on Ubuntu then exported to pdf, and other than some tweaking we need to do to the citation styling he was quite happy with the output. His advise was to use whatever software I was comfortable with (although he had never heard of LaTeX).

I would be grateful for answers from people who have used LaTeX in the Humanities area so as to be best prepared for my own decision on whether or not I would like to use it.

> (Edit 10/03/2014) Just based on some of the answers, especially in
>   relation to the learning curve with LaTeX, here is some more info that
>   may be useful. Probably about 95% of my thesis will be text but I
>   shall also need to insert some images (maps and photos) and will
>   probably be entering some tables with stats. As stated above I use
>   Mendeley for my refernece manager and have read some blogs where this
>   is compatible with LaTeX so I think I would continue to us it if I go
>   the LaTeX route.

Comment: To be fair, how many of the authors of answers suggesting LaTeX have used a *recent* version of MS Word including its advanced bibliography and auto-numbering features, for more than a couple of weeks? As a LaTeX user, I only have a pale remembering of how it all worked with an older version of Word, but one would have to be proficient with both worlds to write a fair unbiased answer.

Comment: I occasionally have to use the most recent version of word. (Mainly when trying to submit an article to a journal that doesn't accept pdf submissions.) My $0.02 is that LaTeX still > recent Word. Although, I admit that MS are adding some nice features, esp on the bib management side.

Comment: The biggest concern for you should be the references, footnotes and cross references, if you can do that seamlessly and painlessly while splitting the document in several pieces with whatever you are using (e.g. Libreoffice) then no need to switch. The second biggest concern is version control and file corruption, as long as you can handle this for your purposes again no need to switch. Switching is an investment (time and effort, it's free), it makes sense iff the ROI is positive.

Comment: One other thing to consider might be to use something like [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) with its LaTeX exporting feature. You write more or less plain text, and then its postprocessor converts your text file into a LaTeX compatible file.

Comment: @Federico Well you still can't share word documents between computers without destroying the formatting, (rather inherent limitation of the WYSIWYG approach) the in every way worse typesetting in Word (Word's justified text..), the horrible math support (I don't enjoy clicking on buttons to create formulas) and the fact that correctly creating general formats in Word is horrible (people trying to imitate springer style in Word always look off), there really is no reason to consider Word for papers in my opinion (which journal accepts word docs anyhow?). But maybe that's just the engineer pov.

Comment: @Voo As a History student (appreciate you're coming from the engineer pov) the math support features won't be a deal-breaker on whether to use LaTeX but I appreciate your opinion with regard to the typesetting & formatting. Can you elaborate on why you think these features are worse in Libreoffice.

Comment: @gman Where to start? The kerning, justification algos(just tested in OO - still not perfect, but a whole lot better than the last time I tried in Word, good!), auto-hyphenation, it doesn't use hardcoded distances between headings and text but allows some variance for better textflow, etc. Or to take one more concrete example: In a well typeset document the whitespace between a dot that ends a sentence and one after say "i.e." should be different.

Comment: And one thing I just can't stress enough: If you send a latex document to a collaborator they will see exactly the same layout you do, while this is almost guaranteed to not be the case for either Word (there's a reason everybody says to only hand in final results in pdf and not doc form!). Basically if you collaborate on a word document, you're forced to do the final formatting and conversion to pdf on one PC and only one (and hoping to make some little change later on without having to fix the layout is everything but guaranteed). Not necessarily a problem, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Voo so have you used a recent version of Word for a significant amount of time? Which one? For how long? Not all your points sound convincing to me. What you list in your second message is what Confused would call "typographical OCD"; re "clicking on buttons to create formulas", I am sure there are hotkeys for everthing.

Comment: @Voo In general I hate formatting anything of any complexity in Word, and simple things can get very frustrating. However, I do have point out that in newer versions the math layout is vastly better and very usable. (OT for a history thesis, I know) It is no longer a weird embedded object. alt-= starts math markup, and you don't need to use the mouse at all if you don't want to. e.g type: \sum_\left<space>n=1\right<space>^\infty<space><space>x^2<space> Things like matrices, equation arrays, etc are handled pretty well.  Definitely useable if you just need to quickly type up an equation.

Comment: @Federico I'll certainly concede that I haven't used Word much since high school (while ago) so I may be missing some parts, true. But you don't have to use a tool to judge the resulting layout of documents and even people without much typographical experience are generally able to distinguish a LaTeX document from a Word document by sight only (they may not be able to tell why one looks appreciably nicer though). I wouldn't call that "typographical OCD" but just "having standards".

Comment: @maybeWeCouldStealAVan Interesting, that didn't work (well?) in Office 2007 and since you could still use the equation editor box thingie in later versions I didn't even think of trying. Good to know when I have to correct some young cousins homework again.

Comment: If you don't do math in your text then the main benefit is that the source is pure text.  This allows you to use programmers tool chests including version control for backing up and that you can write programs that generate graphs that you can \include).  For small tasks the learning curve is most likely too steep, but for a really large written essay it is big enough to pay off.  Also the disconnection between what you type and how it ends up looking mean that you tend to focus on the writing and not on how it ends up looking _while you write_.

Comment: Git is not an argument to use LaTeX. I am writing a PhD in the humanities and I use git with odt2txt implemented to keep my odt files in version control.

Comment: Don't loose time with LaTeX. Trust me, LO and mendeley work fine. They are not as great as M$ Word, but they do the job. And to all the WYSIWYG haters: when you are writing, you only want to focus on the text and not on stuff like `\emph{something important}`. You also do not want to have to compile every two minutes. Moreover, losing the `track changes` option where your promoter can manually change things, saves so much time! Definitely, I moved away from LaTeX for writing in the humanities and I only go back when I have to impress someone. I use a LO plugin to convert to LaTeX if needed.

Comment: The “outline” tools in ms-word are great for organizing your content, the spell checker and grammar checker in word can also come in useful.    Learn how style sheets work in word, and **don’t do any formatting by hand**.   Most word users, blogs, and books **will teach you the wrong way to use word, as they only know how to produce 1 page letters**, I think this is the main reason word is so hated for long documents.

Comment: We are missing some options. How bout InDesign? I've been trying to learn that lately.  Math is great and easy in Word now btw. And you can set these autocorrects so that when you type certain things they automatically change(Ex. I have mine setup so I can type 'eps' and it will change to an epsilon symbol immediately). If you do use LaTeX I would really recommend ShareLatex.com because of the split screen, collaborating, extra options, backing up, access anywhere, & ESPECIALLY because everytime you make a change it keeps a copy of the pre-change document.

Comment: So I downloaded TexMaker and some thesis templates and I going to do some research on how suitable this option is for me. I'll have plenty of free time over this weekend to play around with LaTeX as it's our national holiday (St. Patricks Day) in Ireland and am off for a few days. This way when I meet my supervisor I'll have some practical use of the software under my belt.

Comment: @don.joey Your workflow with git and `odt2txt` seems to work only partially. How can you revert changes or merge two versions, for instance? I am afraid you'll need a `txt2odt` that replicates your formatting for that.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni To be honest, I've never had to merge or revert. Reverting I would do by simply checking out an older commit, copying the odt file, and then moving back to the latest commit, to paste it. When writing, I am not sure you really want to merge a lot (you want to know what you are copying in detail anyway). That said, you have a point that not everything is possible in the workflow I proposed.

Comment: @don.joey ok, no problem, just wanted to check if I was missing some important detail from your description. Still, I agree with what you suggest, that sounds like a good backup/versioning practice. You're right that merging is not that important in a thesis project.

Comment: So I met with my supervisor today and he had no idea was LaTeX was, but was happy with me to use whatever I was comfortable with as long as I could get a pdf to him. He was happy with the format of the LaTeX pdf I had sent him for review and said the department does not have a definitive template as it would probably have all the academics up in arms about what should be in it! So looks like it will be LaTeX.

Comment: Use LaTeX. Why? Because is beautiful: 
 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I'm finishing up a PhD in philosophy that I've written in LaTeX. Here's some suggestions:

- make sure your advisor is ok with leaving you comments in pdf. I suspect they will not understand the question and will not be able to give you any feedback unless you submit chapters in word format. This is a deal breaker. Don't make any more problems communicating with your advisor than absolutely necessary.
- lots of academic journals in the humanities still don't accept submissions in pdf or latex source form. If you are planning on submitting your stuff to a journal, you might save yourself time writing in word format.
- there are some tools available to convert latex to rtf, html and other tools. texht is the best.
- If you do decide to go LaTeX, don't get lost in the minutiae of learning how to tweak everything. It's easy to lose lots of time learning new packages and stuff when you should be writing, writing, writing. Use the wikibooks latex guide as your quick start guide when you need to learn how to do something fast.
- Especially if you're on Ubuntu, don't get the LaTeX distributed through Canonical's repositories. It's usually out of date (haven't checked in a while). Just go on and get the vanilla TexLive 2013 distribution from CTAN.
- The tex.SE site is really, really good. Like ridiculously helpful.
- If you are familiar with version control programs like git, mercurial, or svn you can actually keep a very precise idea of exactly how your thesis has grown over time. You can roll back changes, etc. This is kind of advanced stuff for LaTeX, so I wouldn't spend like a lot of time learning this stuff if you aren't already familiar with it, but if you are, it can be really helpful. EDIT:  Per @henry's comment below, see the following [guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html) by Roger Dudler to get started with git.

Comment: Some very good tips here, Shane, if I do decide to go ahead with LaTeX. Were there many other people using LaTeX in your department such as you're advisor.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 ships with TexLive 2013, so installing by hand shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: There are only 2 or 3 people in my dept who use latex. This has actually made it a little hard, since LaTeX has a little bit of a learning curve and it's nice to be able to pop down the hall and ask a quick question. Still, it isn't impossible to learn on your own. I did!

Comment: + $\inf$ for git. I used it for my thesis in LaTeX and can't stress enough how helpful this was.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm aware of very few people outside of science that use Linux at all...

Comment: @biologue Nitpicking, but `$\inf$` is LaTeX for the infimum operator. You're looking for `$\infty$`.

Comment: @Mike I don't doubt that, but the authors of the question and of the answer we're commenting on are two liberal-art majors discussing which version of LaTeX to install in Ubuntu; that's what my comment is catering to.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I hadn't paid enough attention to see that they're Ubuntu users. My apologies!

Comment: @Mike Yes I am one of those few. For work I'm still stuck with windows but on my personal computer I made the switch to ubuntu about 18 months ago and have never looked back. Yes the computers in my liberal arts labs are all windows afaik but I do 99.9% of my work on my own laptop connected to the universitys' network.

Comment: *there are some tools available to convert latex to rtf, html and other tools. text is the best. * — when I needed it, I actually had better experiences converting the resulting PDF to Word.

Comment: Great tips from Shane. Before you choose MSW or Latex, try to find a template document for both. Give it a test drive, and verify that the result fits in your dept guide lines. If you choose Latex, as your team seems to use MSW, you'll need to find a team who will help you fix layout issues when they happen. Latex is great, allows you to focus on writing stuff, as opposed to spending countless hours trying to fix that damn table that jumped to the other page, cascading into an impossible alignment mess for all your figures, tables, pictures...

Comment: "The tex.SE site is really, really good. Like ridiculously helpful." Seconded. Where else can you find TeX experts falling over themselves to answer your questions? They are very friendly to beginners, a trait which, unfortunately, is not common on tech sites, including those that form part of the SE network. Also, if you can't find something by searching on the site, they don't mind if you ask in chat. Maybe someone can point you in the right direction. An example of their good attitude - downvoting is generally frowned on past -1.

Comment: @Alex I have a pretty good template document for Libreoffice that has set up styles/formatting etc that should do everything I need. Good idea though to give a template a test drive in LaTeX.

Comment: @gman be cautious to find one that does match the document layout guide lines of your department (Thesis are sometimes printed, made available via online libraries etc...) try scout in your humanity department, for a proper template. Good luck ! (and just in case, as Shane suggested, svn/git are great tools for version control, not that hard to use. SVN is very straightforward.)

Comment: +1 for using VCS for your thesis. This makes it _much_ easier to maintain backups (which you definitely want to have for a thesis like this). No more checking which backup is newer, when it was created, whether it already contains the last chapter…

Comment: Even though Git can be quite a mouthful to learn from scratch, [Legit](http://www.git-legit.org/) makes working with it (at the most basic level, more than enough for this case) a breeze and a pleasure! Highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to Legit. I'm still just breaking into version control stuff and wishing I had done it ages ago.

Comment: @shane It is actually not all that difficult. I use `git gui` and the usual `git` in the command line on both Linux (Xubuntu 13.10) and Windows (7) daily. [For starters, the guide by Roger Dudler definitely is the way to go.](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.html) Imho, if you follow the advice on there and know how to google properly, that's all you need to read for an introduction. While I didn't perceive you as a truly new `git` user, you could maybe include this link for your last bullet point in your answer? :)

Comment: May i suggest to replace the wikibook stuff by [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) and [Using LaTeX to write a PhD](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html)? The wikibook really isn't good.

Comment: From my personal expirience, not-learning LaTeX saves a lot of time, but debugging Word document (figures and tables [re]positioning, labeling, enumerating, etc.) wastes much more time than saved...

Comment: LibreOffice has version control inside a document inside it. No absolute necessity to use Git

Answer (score 44):

When my husband did his master's, he used LaTeX to write his thesis even though his supervisor preferred Word and everyone else in his lab used Word.  He encountered some pros and cons.

***Pros of using LaTeX:***

- Word gets very slow and buggy once your documents are past a certain length, say forty or fifty pages.  One of my husband's friends spent a day renumbering all of the figures in his thesis after the numbers mysteriously disappeared.  I'm not sure if this issue exists with LibreOffice, but it may.
- You mentioned breaking your thesis into smaller documents and combining them later.  This is easily and commonly done with LaTeX; <s>it would be considerably harder with LibreOffice</s>. [Edit: [derobert](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17961/should-i-learn-to-use-latex-to-write-up-a-history-masters-thesis#comment36232_17967) pointed out that LibreOffice supports this through a "master document" feature.  I wasn't familiar with it.]
- It's much easier to change the formatting of the document at the last minute if you discover that, e.g., your margins don't match your university's specifications or your references are formatted incorrectly.  It's also easier to keep the formatting consistent.
- The results are more aesthetically pleasing, if you care about things like ligatures and kerning.

***Cons of using LaTeX:***

- LaTeX has a much steeper learning curve, as others have mentioned.  If you don't need to use it after you're done your thesis, it may not be worth the time investment.
- LaTeX forces a slightly different editing workflow since you can't turn on Track Changes.  Your supervisor will have to mark up the PDFs you produce or add comments to the tex file itself.  This may make your supervisor less happy about your choice.

My recommendation: use LaTeX to write up something short that you need to write anyway to see how it works.  Then play around with some of the features you'll need for a thesis: add a footnote, a reference, or a figure.  Try the \include command, too.  That should give you a sense of whether it's something you want to continue with.

Comment: Track changes is possible in latex: http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/

Comment: A more sound alternative for tracking changes is a version control software (such as git or mercurial) + latexdiff. Of course, this doubles the steepness of the learning curve for you initially.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Version control is great, I agree, but it doesn't help with editing if gman's supervisor doesn't know how to use it. For example, I use git, so my supervisor compares drafts with git diff --word-diff. gman's supervisor probably doesn't know how to do that.

Comment: @lmi You can make good use of version control even if your supervisor/coauthor has no idea how to use it; just run it for yourself. When you give them a new version, run it through `latexdiff` and send the output as well. When you receive a new version from them, commit it with `--author=SupervisorName` and merge the changes.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I hadn't thought of just sending the diff -- that's a really good idea.

Comment: @Imi, not sure about my supervisors' tech skills, which may be an issue. He was unaware of Mendeley so would guess no knowledge of LaTeX. At the moment I email pdf exported from Libreoffice which he prints and I get back with handwritten notes

Comment: I would also recommend trying different fonts, such as Palatino (the `mathpazo` package). Combined with `microtype` (essential!) and a class style like `memoir` or `classicthesis`, the quality of the resulting typography would (in my opinion as a perfectionist) be well worth the pain of dealing with colleagues and supervisors that don't use LaTeX.

Comment: @gman Even better then: printing pdf's and receiving hand-written comments is a workflow that translates perfectly well to LaTeX. It would have been way harder if your supervisor used advanced Word commenting/multi-author features. :)

Comment: If you do write a large document in Word, it's much more stable if you use styles everywhere instead of inline markup.  Word headings, captions, numbered lists, etc are all done using styles; if you change formatting using the bold/underline/etc toolbar buttons instead of creating/editing styles you're mixing inline markup into the document.  Mixing the two ways of format will turn large documents into unstable messes.  Large numbers of tracked changes can cause similar problems; unfortunately there's no easy way to only mark old changes read unless you play games with your track changes name.

Comment: FYI: LibreOffice actually supports breaking a large document into multiple smaller ones, they call this feature a [master document](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Master_Documents_and_Subdocuments).

Comment: @derobert Good to know! I wasn't familiar with that feature.

Comment: In my experience large documents (+300 pages including equations) is no longer a problem in modern MS Word.

Answer (score 18):

> I'm sure how familiarity or usage of LaTeX within the History department will impact on my decision but would also like to prepare my thesis in the best possible way.

I would say that it should impact your decision strongly. You should prefer a tool that is used by your colleagues and supervisor to one that is slightly better intrinsically. They are the people who know what you need to do, and how to accomplish it with the tools they know.

I personally prefer LaTeX to LibreOffice, but I would guess that the combination of LibreOffice and Mendeley have all the features you need. (One in particular that I'm going to call out is change-tracking. *Enable it as soon as you start, or you'll wish you had before long*.) But the advantage of knowing your tool and having colleagues who know your tool outweigh most of LaTeX's advantages.

Comment: I didn't know about the change tracking, was going to use comments. Just enabled it and have being doing some writing and its great. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: One of the biggest problems with word is that when putting the finishing touches to the document (i.e. formatting everything) you really can work on one and *only* one computer. It's basically impossible to keep the exact same formatting when sending word docs from one PC to another (and don't even think about mixing versions). That's a pretty big downside in my opinion, ignoring all the other problems with word (Word 2010 still can't justify text reasonably, no idea if they got that one fixed in the newer versions).

Answer (score 13):

I recently made the mistake of writing a novel with each chapter as a separate document in LibreOffice. When I needed to combine them all into a single document, it wasn't pleasant. So that might be a consideration, depending on how many chapters your thesis has. As Imi mentioned, LaTeX definitely has better support for combining documents.

You might be interested in [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/). It's a word processor that uses LaTeX as a backend. You can get almost all of the abilities of LaTeX, but the learning curve is a lot shallower since it has more of the standard word processor features. It's a big help in following shane's advice not to get caught up in the minutiae of LaTeX. I use it for linguistics, where it seems to be pretty widely known. (Linguists have some of the same typesetting challenges as the math people). Newer versions have change tracking, as landroni mentions in the comments. Also, if you do decide to use source control, LyX can help you manage it, although it might take some coercion to set it up. LyX uses its own file format by default, but you can export to LaTeX.

As shane also mentioned, there are tools to convert LaTeX into other formats. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html) can even convert LaTeX into Word or Open Office format. Both LyX and Pandoc are available for Ubuntu.

So what I would probably do in your situation is write in LyX or LaTeX, then use Pandoc to export that to docx or odt for your advisor. You can read your advisor's comments in Word, make changes to your original, and export again. It sounds convoluted, but I do think you'll gain a lot in flexibility and tool support over using LibreOffice.

**EDIT**: Yes, you probably will have to put in some extra work to make the docx files generated by Pandoc usable. On the other hand, LyX and LaTeX can also save you a ton of time that you might have used struggling with LibreOffice's primitive support for pictures and formatting. (And special characters, not relevant to the OP's case, but very much so if you're doing linguistics or math.) If you're not sure, try testing your workflow on a small document: write something in LyX or LaTeX, convert it to odt or docx with Pandoc, and do the work to get the odt or docx file into a usable state. See whether you think it's worth it for what you're doing.

Comment: lyx is a nice halfway tool. Thanks for pointing it out. I originally started with lys and eventually decided I wanted to see what was going on "under the hood" and after a while I just preferred to write the code straight.

Comment: LyX DOES have Change Tracking. It works well as far as I hear.

Comment: For info, exporting from LyX to ODT via pandoc is more of a hassle than it may seem at first. If you need ODT as the final output, for a novice you may as well stay with Word-like clones.

Comment: @landroni: You're right, I was looking at outdated docs. Sorry about that.

Comment: Additional benefits of LyX: (1) easy (gui) import/export for .rtf, which would make it easy if you need to switch between programs for any reason (2) deals with auxiliary files cleanly and automatically, (3) easy BibTeX, especially if you're doing in-line citations that are author (year), (author year), athor et al (year), or whatever crazy thing you want (though historians probably favor footnotes?).

Answer (score 12):

For some people, the crucial features of LaTeX are portability and permanence. With LibreOffice and (especially) MS Word, you are essentially at the mercy of whether developers decide to make all future versions backwards compatible (I have a couple of papers I wrote in grad school that are effectively inaccessible until I find a machine with MS Word 98 for Windows). In contrast, with LaTeX, the source file is just plain ASCII text, so it will be forever readable and editable in any computer, regardless of operating system.

If your advisor is not LaTeX-friendly, you can have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829408/extract-text-from-tex-remove-latex-tags), the answers to which provide a number of tools to strip all LaTeX tags from a file, so you are left only with the plain text. From my experience, that is an acceptable compromise to most people.

Comment: It's not entirely true. Even with LaTeX, packages change and you may not be able to reproduce the exact same result with a later version. You can always recover the text, that's true, but the same holds for Word: a `.docx` is just a zipped xml file.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: With TeX archiving your whole environment (including all used packages) and using exactly that two decades later is _easy_ while the same will be extremely hard with *Office.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Still not convinced. How do you archive your whole environment? Is it easier than installing an older version of Word in, say, a virtual machine?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: With TeX you can easily archive all input files (i.e. the complete TeX distribution). And since it's open source and portable and stable, you can archive the sources for the binaries (and if you want the operating system (Linux, BSD)) and recreate them later. It's still much simpler than with closed source software like Microsoft Office or complex free software like LibreOffice.

Answer (score 8):

It is quite likely your advisor has never heard of LaTeX, so don't expect too much from discussing it with him.

LaTeX has a fairly steep learning curve but it is good for working with references and *great* for working with math.  Since you don't need the latter at all, it may not be worth the effort for you.

Comment: Just for grins, go up to your advisor and say, "I'd like to write my thesis in Lahtech with PDF output." If he gets that deer-in-the-headlights look (very likely), you'll know you're out of luck. On the other hand, he may only want a hardcopy of the thing, in which case you may be free to use whatever you want. Most likely, you will be required to supply at least the finished result, if not the original source, in some specific format that your department uses. That may relieve you of the choice... Certainly _play_ with LaTeX ahead of time, but don't invest a lot in it yet.

Answer (score 8):

To answer the question with a clear yes or no would be to oversimplify things. LaTeX is used for much more than just mathematics so I would not hesitate from that point of view. Learning something new is always useful so again, no argument there. What you need to ask yourself is if you are interested in learning LaTeX. this may depend on whether or not there are others using it in your neighbourhood. Being completely alone is tougher than having some other persons with whom to work when learning. Another question is to what extent LaTeX is used in your field for journal publications etc. So, try to assess how much use you will have in your field from learning it. Since LaTeX can be used for writing papers, books and reports as well as for making presentations (a la PowerPoint) and posters, it includes bibliography handling, it is a very useful tool for any field for scientific writing.

Comment: Very valid points Peter. I would be interested in learning something new but as a part-time student it can be hard to get time to interact with groups that may be learning. That's something I'll have to check out in my university if there is a LaTeX group.

Comment: @gman [TeX.StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com) and the [LaTeX section in Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/) are both excellent resources.

Answer (score 7):

**Yes...unless...**

You will have references, many of them.  Managing references is a complete pain without the facilities provided by LaTeX or one of the often  expensive tools for word (there may be something free for libreoffice, and it may be good).  It may be a little easier with the citation styles typical in humanities/social sciences than it is for physical sciences, but still not easy.  So unless you have access to a good tool for managing your citations in your wordprocessor, just go for LaTeX.

Cross-referencing between sections and to figures/tables is also much easier.

You *may* find a tool like LyX suits you - or you may like the freedom of just getting on with it in a decent text editor.  [This list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) may be helpful in that regard.

I can thoroughly support the view expressed above that you should start on a smaller document.

When it comes to commenting by your adviser, such as for a dissertation, pdf comments on your work, or handwritten comments are fine, but for collaborative writing of a paper with non-LaTeX users things become *a lot* harder unless you're in charge.

[Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/) by Nicola Talbot is well worth a read, it's from a CS background but don't let that put you off, it's clear and well written.

On the other hand, if you start writing in a word processor, you will end up sticking with it, which is fine, plenty of theses get written that way, but nobody ever finds the time to switch from one system to the other.

Also note that if you use libreoffice and you work with people who use MSoffice (or even for different versions of MSoffice) change tracking is rather fragile.

Comment: TO update this ten years on: There are now a good many free, and good, reference management tools for Word

Answer (score 6):

I would say it is worth your time and effort, not that the effort required would be great, as other have said first off talk to your professor and ask if he has any opinions on the matter.

I wrote the paper for my B.Sc. in LaTeX and to do so I learned it mostly by myself, with some help from some post grads but those were for issues you will not hit when writing an historical paper, in the spare moments between actually writing the code my paper was about.

Like yourself my paper didn't involve large swathes of mathematical formulas with lots of Greek letters but it did require almost Swiss-like precision, and I felt that with my limited command of Word I would be better of just starting from scratch with LaTex and knowing exactly the cause effect relationship between my actions and the document's presentation (I was and still am weary of losing all my formatting in Word due to a slip of the mouse).

Some of LaTex's strongest points in its favor is the ease with which it can handle citations for you as well as index your pictures, give them captions and etc.

The fact that you use Linux already is also a factor as setting up a good LaTex editor on Ubuntu seems much easier than on Windows to me, I highly recommend Kile as the editor it's not WYSIWG but it will keep you from making syntax errors due to the large amount of LaTeX snippets available and it also simplifies the "make a pdf from all this mark-up" process.

Another point in LaTex's favour is the very friendly and responsive community at [the Tex exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

I have to be honest that it was very easy for me to pick up LaTeX because I already had experience with HTML which is also a mark-up language, but in my opinion if you understand what happens when you bold a word on a Stack Exchange site (see the *** *** and their effect) then you can understand LaTeX.

Comment: Yes I also have a little experience of using html as have done some website work in my spare time. Good to know this would help with LaTeX.

Comment: @gman It will help tremendously.

Answer (score 6):

All mentioned pros and cons are valid, but... LaTeX is written by smart people for use by smart people. Word is written by smart people for everyone, including dumb people. Take your pick. For me, 5 dissertation years spent with LaTeX as an everyday companion was thoroughly enjoyable.

Answer (score 5):

If you're considering other software besides just Microsoft Word or LaTeX, then I would put a vote in for [Scrivener](http://literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php), which I switched to halfway through my Masters (submitted in December).

Scrivener is a bit LaTeXy in that it separates the composition from the formatting, with the latter done as a single rendering process at the end, but it also allows a high degree of style and formatting while you write, however this should be viewed as a 'preview' rather than actual formatting.

It was originally designed for novelists, but there's a growing community of academics using it going on the posts in the forums. I found it great for handling things like numbered lists such as figures and tables, and, particularly important for linguistics, example sentences.

The basic workflow is that you compose in Scrivener and then 'compile', which will format the entire document and apply formatting in a single hit, then you can either print directly, or if you need further post-processing (like Endnote), then output as a useful format for you and take it to whatever program you need. My workflow was to go into Word and run Endnote, plus a couple of other small tasks, and then print. For a 50,000 word document, my time spent in Word was about 3 hours (including proofing). Scrivener also supports compiling to a LaTeX document using MultiMarkDown syntax.

Anyway, some dot-points:

**Pros:**

- Great hierarchical sectioning support, in fact this is key to its organisational structure
- Secure in terms of text data, which is stored in individual text files (one for each section/subsection)
- Much easier to learn than LaTeX
- Support available from the forum from the developers, and very quick response from them (I once suggested a feature and it was rolled-out two days later)
- Good support for multiple independent numbered lists (tables, figures)
- Good support for cross-referencing to chapters and sections
- You can output to .doc or .rtf and have track changes, but see last Con.

**Cons:**

- Not free; $40 (PC) $45 (Mac) once-off purchase (free 30-day trial, free for Linux)
- Originally designed for Mac, and other operating systems are still catching up on features. There is a [Linux](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33) release but it is in beta (however the features that are missing only affect the compile process, so you could conceivably write in Ubuntu and compile on Mac)
- No support for Endnote apart from mapping ctrl/cmd-Y to open Endnote, that is, scrivener does not insert formatted bibliographic citations either in-line or as endnotes (but if you work using raw field codes, then pass them through to Word, it works great)
- Formatting presets in Scrivener do not map to 'styles' in Word (although again, there are workarounds)
- Not intended to be a complete typesetting program, but a writing program. You should expect to have to post-process your document in another program.
- Importing from Word is not very good. This will affect what you do with track changes and supervisor's comments (you'd have to incorporate them yourself manually).

Sorry about the plug – I do not receive any kind of support from the makers of Scrivener; I just think it's the best writing software I've used, and since you're trying to weigh up the benefits and costs of switching to LaTeX, I definitely think you should consider it since it is compatible with LaTeX anyway, and is much easier to work in.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitively learn LaTeX.

MS Word is slow, is instable, and the document is just, if you are not a guru at Word, ugly. You need a lot of expertise to control the blank spaces between words, to get a line break correct, to avoid orphan lines, etc., not to mention more advanced things related to type setting.

The ease to use of MS Word is not real ease. It just makes any secretary think he/she can use it. For a two page document this might be OK, but actually it requires a lot of experience to get a document right.

I don't agree that LaTeX has a steep learning curve. There are tools which make LaTeX pretty much WYSIWYG. Read the first two or three chapters of an introductory LaTeX book, install miktex and simatra PDF viewer on your windows, use EclipseTex for editing, it's pretty easy, and it does not required you to be a rocket scientist to type set documents that are nice to see.

You'll love LaTeX once you started using it. You'll wonder how it is ever possible to use Word any more.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely no.

This may sound like a flippant response but it's actually grounded in experience and much thought.

I'm in a STEM discipline where LaTeX is considered by faculty to be the ONLY way to do word processing so I've had time to really formulate my viewpoint here.

Note: I use Word here but I assume LibreOffice is of the same quality/functionality.

1. Latex *used to be better* than Word in terms of controlling your document with precision and with things like formatting, bibliographies, and equations. Now that word has evolved to it's current state there is no advantage to LaTeX unless, as someone has already mentioned, you are into kerning and typography-type stuff. You can easily adjust margins, bibliographies, styles, equations, etc in Word these days. It's just which you learned the idiosyncrasies of first and more thoroughly.
2. Word is easier and more universally accepted. Everyone knows what to do with a docx file. What would a older professor who may not be a tech person in a history dept know what to do with .tex, .cls, .bib, or .ttf files? If you wanted to get feedback you'd have to put it into pdf and then getting comments would be annoying as others have mentioned.
3. I just used LaTeX for the first time to write 2 papers in the past couple weeks. I used the ShareLatex site and a template from an academic journal in my area. Without ShareLatex I could not have done it in a timely fashion. It does automatic versioning the entire time(at least for the time I used it). So every single time you make a change it keeps a copy of the document before the change. You can share it with others as the name implies and it will function like Google Docs in this regard. You can specify which compiler you want to use and some other options. It also lets you upload any and all files you might have associated with your document including fonts, images, template class files, etc. The only issue is when fine tuning formatting things make sure you look at the pdf because the little preview display isn't as high fidelity.
4. Inserting figures can be annoying. Especially with various file types. I had to convert all my figures to jpeg's to avoid issues I had with png's. They don't always go where you put them. LaTeX puts them where ever it sees fit. Yes there are settings to try to force LaTeX to put them where you want instead of where it wants but do you really need to be having a fight of wills with your word processor???

Summary: There is just absolutely no reason I can see to use LaTeX for the average person who is not OCD about kerning, ligatures and pristine fonts. Yes, it's fun at first playing with all the options and features but after awhile you just yearn for the simplicity of Word. In past years before the current state of mainstream word processors maybe LaTeX had it's advantage but now I get better results using Word and it's equation editor and formatting tools than with LaTeX. If you don't have equations and scientific things to display, as I suspect you might not, I would just write it in Word. If you want to play around with LaTeX for the typography aspects then copy what you've written into a .tex which you can then experiment with the nitpicky font details and see that when it's all said and done... the difference in output may be imperceptible.

Comment: I upvoted this to cancel the downvote, not because I think it's the right answer, but because it's a reasonable contribution to the OPs quandary.

Comment: Didn't downvote but this seems slightly biased. Some of the TeX problems you mention sound more like a lack of experience.

Comment: It is biased. Why wouldn't I be biased against what I consider to be an inferior approach? Your comment even exemplifies the whole point of why I'm anti-LaTeX. Why should one learn what is a programming language to do something he/she already knows how to do in Word? The only advantage I experienced was being able to easily change the spacing around mathematical operators in my equations. As the OP is a history major I don't think he/she will be taking advantage of that ability much. In the past LaTeX was useful for the average writer but now it's just a relic from the pre-decent-Word era.

Comment: *This may sound like a flippant response but it's actually grounded in experience* [...] *I just used LaTeX for the first time to write 2 papers in the past couple weeks.* That's the problem. LaTeX has a steep learning curve, no one here is denying it. You can't expect to use it for two weeks and know enough about it to brand it as useless. How long have you been using Word in comparison?

Comment: Word has actually been quite powerful when it comes to doing things that academic papers require for quite some time (I remember doing this stuff in Word 6.0 and it working very well). The problem is that those features actually have a bit of a learning curve, so much so that people *don't use them*.

Comment: In fairness I think it's good to the anti-LaTeX view as well. I have used Libreoffice to good effect to date and am comfortable using it. Like other answers, Confused I think, has highlighted some of the pitfalls I may encounter by switching. A the moment the learning curve would not be the deal breaker as I like learning tech as well.

Comment: To summarise the answer: "*LaTeX is harder and the same things can be done in ___Office*". This is only true for when you are stuck on the learning curve of LaTeX. But when you get more experience and you get to appreciate the power of user-contributed packages like `pgfplots`, `tikz`, `siunitx`, `booktabs`, `longtable`, as well as the various styles, fonts and bib packages ... you see what they can offer that no ___Office can! And after you immerse yourself in LaTeX for a while, you see that the typographical differences are not at all OCD but rather a greater appreciation for clear layout.

Comment: I'm really tempted to downvote this, but I won't. It is good to have different points of view, I'll say that. However, 2 weeks is next to no time to learn something like TeX/LaTeX. I've been using LaTeX since the late 90s, and I've only really learned much in the last few years, largely thanks to the tex.sx site.

Comment: I still have problems on my country to open a docx file... just saying.

Comment: 1. Simply wrong. I use Word (when forced) and it still can't get simple things like section references right (they're regularly lost as the document evolves and the only warning you get is “**Error! Reference source not found.**” in your printout). Styles can be done in Word, but the capabilities are limited. Forget indexing, unless it's improved after Word 2007 (I haven't tried recently). 2. That depends on the discipline and location. (cont.)

Comment: 3. Well, yes, LaTeX doesn't do version control, that's not its job. There's specialized software for that. Word's built-in support is nice until you reach its limits, which is soon (e.g. all changed reference targets appear as changes, all kinds of spurious formatting changes come up). 4. Inserting figures in Word? Yeech. I always have to fight it to get the figures not to overlap the text, and its built-in diagram editor tends to move bits around willy-nilly. LaTeX's figure placement isn't a panacea but it's easier to get not completely wrong.

Comment: Just in relation to points 2 & 4. 2. LaTeX can export to pdf which is how I currently send my work onto my supervisor and I get hand written comments back so I don't think that will effect my work flow. 4. I will probably have about 5 maps, less than 10 tables and at max about 10-15 images to insert so I think I shall be able to standardise all my content. My girlfriend is graphic/web designer so will get some guidance on formats there.

Comment: So, Word 2007 is roughly 7 years old. Yes, the features have improved! :)

Comment: To the rest of the pro-Texxers I didn't say LaTeX was useless. I come from an academic environment where we are extremely heavily pressured to use LaTeX for every little thing and I just don't see the reason for it. I make beautiful equations in Word, neat diagrams in GraphViz, insert said diagrams in Word, manage & insert citations in Word with a couple of clicks. I guess I think of Word as a GUI that probably hides a LaTeX system underneath(just how I think of it, probably not factual). Why go through the anti-usability of LaTeX when there's a great GUI unless you're doing something unusual?

Comment: The question I posed in an earlier comment has STILL not been answered, "Why should one learn what is a programming language to do something he/she already knows how to do in Word?" And when I say Word I mean a ____Office word processor released in 2010 or later since let's not go skewing the comparison (next let's comparing Windows 3.1 Vs Ubuntu 13.10   ;) ).

Comment: @Confused It's all well that MS Office's features are constantly improving, but I'm reluctant on spending my money on it every 2-3 years when LaTeX is free. Otherwise, very good answer.

Comment: @Confused, I'm glad to have your anti-LaTeX answer in order to balance out the pro-LaTeX answers above. As to your question, "Why should one learn what is a programming language to do something he/she already knows how to do in Word?" I began using LaTeX while taking Physics in a summer semester. We had to write lab reports twice a week. Naturally, I picked Word at first, mainly for speed. But my graphs and figures, which looked perfect on the screen, were almost illegible when printed (on a laser printer). So I buckled down, learned LaTeX, and swooned over the results. That's why.

Answer (score 3):

**YES... and why not use both!**

The learning curve for *using* LaTeX (with a good template) is actually relatively small, and will save you time/headaches in a large document such as a thesis since the formatting is automatically taken care of, and probably looks much better too (especially equations). Just paste your text into a .tex template, and create a .bib file.

My process is to write the draft (unformatted text) in LibreOffice with each chapter as a separate document, referencing with tags only, and storing the figures in a separate folder. The reason is that I find it easier to think/edit in WYSIWYG. Once I am happy with the draft it takes **minimal effort** to transfer it to LaTeX: I just go through and create a .bib file from copy and paste EndNote entries whilst I am inserting reference tags.

The end result looks perfect and I have saved time, avoiding the formatting problems that plagued my MS word undergraduate thesis.

Answer (score 3):

I think using dynamic documents is the only way to ensure your work is reproducible. Latex is an important tool in my workflow that helps me achieve this aim, and I view it as a necessity. Word documents are simply not reproducible.

**You can read about the issues with Word [here](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/Please_don't_send_me_Microsoft_Word_documents), [here](http://thewritelife.com/microsoft-word-just-say-no/), [here](http://factorgrad.blogspot.com/2010/07/why-latex-is-superior-to-ms-word.html) and [here](http://gribblelab.org/scicomp/07_Document_processing.html).**

If you adopt latex you should also use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), which I don't think anyone mentioned here. Pandoc allows you to convert a document to range of other document types with a simple line of code. I'm imagining the person who tries to cut and paste from the latex generated PDF into a Word document because that is what their advisor wants. Pandoc will make your life easier.

Scrivener is also another nice option that will allow you to write in markdown, it converts to latex on the backend and then converts the latex to pdf. Scrivener is also a great companion for long-form writing.

To the person that said:  "You should prefer a tool that is used by your colleagues and supervisor to one that is slightly better intrinsically." I'd argue that you should use the tool that gets the work done most efficiently for you. Latex is going to save you so much time in terms of formatting the document. So, please explain to me why anyone expect that I use a tool that's going to require me to needlessly spend hours out of my productive schedule to tweak the formatting of the document over and over again? Your whole statement is anti-progress.

Comment: To be fair, I have spend hours tweaking the formatting of a document in LaTeX, too.

Answer (score 3):

First, I am a mathematician.

I see no reason whatsoever to use LaTeX for humanities work. I think the best tool to write regular texts or books without formulas is LibreOffice.

I write my non-scientific (and even some mathematical) works in LibreOffice.

This is despite I have rather expert knowledge of LaTeX, I don't like to use it unless strictly necessary.

LibreOffice handles images and tables well. Just learn to use it.

Answer (score 2):

A contrary view, perhaps, but: NO.

If you take the time to learn how to use word *properly* - understanding styles, using a good reference manager with a Word plugin, and so forth, then it is capable (but keep many backups).

LaTeX is a better tool, but there's a significant amount of time and effort needed to learn it. In STEM fields this is often a good investment for one's future career, but in history you are unlikely to be working with other people who use LaTeX, so future manuscripts etc are likely to have to be in Word to fit with co-authors.

Spend your time using your long-term tool (Word) well - which is not how most people use it - rather than learning a tool that you will be the only user of in future collaborations.