# How can code be classified in a Thesis(Figure, Table, Listing, etc)

Tags: thesis, formatting

I am writing a Thesis and there are sections that require me to add fragments of code or a complete code. Should this be classified as a figure, table,listing or snippet ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Insert it as a [listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Listing_%28computer%29). The convention is to print code verbatim in monospace font. If you're writing in LaTeX, the [`listings`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings) package exists for this purpose.

Comment: While this is helpful for LaTeX users, it doesn't tell @beginningperl how to label it.

Comment: @BillBarth Yes it does. It is a listing - that is what it is called. You can have listings labelled 1.1, 1.2, 2.1 etc just like figures, and a List of Listings (or perhaps Code Listings) in the TOC.

Comment: Withdrawn. You're right. I hadn't used that feature before. Not sure how I missed it. +1

Comment: One quick addition, you'll probably want to use `\lstlistoflistings` to produce an appropriate Table of Listings at the front of your document. The optional arguments `label=someAwesomeLabel` and `caption={This is my caption}` are also very helpful.

Comment: @Moriarty Thank you very much for your reply. I thought about the listing to but wasn't sure. I am using Microsoft word and since it doesn't have that label, i could create a custom label as listing. I will leave the question open for now should anyone have any other answers.

Comment: @beginningperl Might I add that if you are writing a thesis about software, there is no reason to stick to Word. The learning curve of LaTeX is shallower than that of HTML, and the [advantages outweigh the cost of learning it](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5414/what-are-the-advantages-or-disadvantages-of-using-latex-for-writing-scientific-p).

Comment: @JonathanLandrum Thanks i will take some time to learn it.